# str_replace Not Working Well PHP

Tags: php, tags, str-replace

I've got two strings that are lines pulled from a file. I'm trying to first strip them of their tags (like ) by doing a str_replace and replacing them with a space. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working because when I echo out the results in the form I still see the tags.

Any ideas?

```
# Trim the title and description of their tags. Keep only text.
$title_new = $file_lines[$title_line];
str_replace("<title>"," ", $title_new);
str_replace("</title>"," ", $title_new);

$desc_new = $file_lines[$desc_line];
str_replace("<description>"," ", $desc_new);
str_replace("</description>"," ", $desc_new);

# Echo out the HTML form
echo "<form action=\"rewrite.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "Title: <input type=\"text\" name=\"new_title\" size=\"84\" value=\"".$title_new."\">";
echo "</input>";

echo "<br>Article Body:<br>";
echo "<textarea rows=\"20\" cols=\"100\" wrap=\"hard\" name=\"new_desc\">".$desc_new."</textarea><br>";

echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"title_line\" value=\"".$title_line."\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"title_old\" value=\"".$file_lines[$title_line]."\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"desc_line\" value=\"".$desc_line."\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"desc_old\" value=\"".$file_lines[$desc_line]."\">";

echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Modify\" name=\"new_submit\">";
```

Comment: First day writing PHP, cut me some slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $title_new = str_replace(array("<title>", "</title>")," ", $file_lines[$title_line]);
 $desc_new = str_replace(array("<description>","</description>")," ", $file_lines[$desc_line]);
```

Or use

> strip_tags

Answer (score 4):

[str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) returns the modified string. So you need to assign it:

```
$title_new = str_replace("<title>"," ", $title_new);
```

Same with `$desc_new`. Read the docs for more detail.

Comment: Goddamn that's the second time -_- Thanks :) I'm way too tired.

Comment: No worries. Per the comments, I agree that `strip_tags()` might be a better function in this case.

Answer (score 2):

str_replace returns the string, so you should have done this:

```
$title_new = str_replace("<title>"," ", $title_new);
$title_new = str_replace("</title>"," ", $title_new);
$desc_new = str_replace("<description>"," ", $desc_new);
$desc_new = str_replace("</description>"," ", $desc_new);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to strip tags, when using PHP, is [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

I wouldn't try doing something like that with str_replace. Most likely one'd make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned you need to assign the return value like `$title_new = str_replace("<title>"," ", $title_new);`, but I highly encourage you to use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for its intended purpose.

```
$buffer = strip_tags($buffer, '<title><description>')
```

Also it's likely unnecessary to parse the file line by line. It would be many times faster to read the whole file at once with something like `file_get_contents()` and then use a regular expression or an xml parser.